# How to run a external python script that is run infinitely in Django and print all the outputs in html?

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, django-celery

I have a python script that in an infinite loop get some data from a URL and saves it in a database. it prints some logs and sometimes it throws some errors. my script is as follow:

```
   dbclient = MongoClient('127.0.0.1')
   db = dbclient.shell
   while True:
       url = "http://example.com/api"
       print("request has been sent====================")
       response = requests.get(url).json()
       print("data has been downloaded====================")
       db.api_backup.insert_many(response)
       print("data has been saved in MongoDB====================")
```

Now, I have created a Django project for monitoring. So, I want to able to start and stop it by a button on an Html page and see its status and outputs(like what is seen in the terminal).
It seems I should use a task Queue like Celery. But the problem is how to execute this script in Celery. I need to check its status and show its outputs periodically(every 3 minutes).
How can I do it?
thanks in advance.

Comment: you would need to use some kind of [task queue](https://www.fullstackpython.com/task-queues.html)

Comment: is it possible to give an example to show how it works?

Comment: take a tour through the examples and documentation, there are even examples with django. Then if you have a specific question come back to stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

This is a nice little package for simple queue jobs and its very easy to use

https://python-rq.org/

You start with a server:

```
import requests

def count_words_at_url(url):
    resp = requests.get(url)
    return len(resp.text.split())
```

then create a queue:

```
from redis import Redis
from rq import Queue

q = Queue(connection=Redis())
```

and the function call

```
from my_module import count_words_at_url
result = q.enqueue(
             count_words_at_url, 'http://nvie.com')
```

For more complex stuff you can read the docs here:

https://python-rq.org/docs/